# Why do I need to import types by referring to a non-existent module?

Tags: typescript

I need to import the `Plugin` type from [this file](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/types/index.esm.d.ts)

First attempt to pull in:

`import {Plugin} from 'chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts';`

This yields:

> An import path cannot end with a '.d.ts' extension. Consider importing 'chart.js/types/index.esm.js' instead.

So I update to:

`import {Plugin} from 'chart.js/types/index.esm.d.js';`

And now there are no complaints, but that file doesn't exist on disk. Why is this working?

I also note that this also works:

`import {Plugin} from 'chart.js/types/index.esm.d';`

Which is the best practice?

Comment: Given that it seems to be [set up correctly](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/a5b46a859c6398618ec4787222b35bdd09b9f834/package.json#L11), can't you `import { Plugin } from "chart.js"`?

Comment: Reaching into the bowels of npm packages isn't really advised unless the documentations specifically tell you to. @jonesharpe's suggestion is right, and [works fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgBQDYFcDmwB2cC+cAZlBCHAEQDGAFgIawB0AVgM4UCwAUNwCYCmVVA35wqEHK3hgM2HAC4Us3HAD0quAHdoAa1ZA) to get and use the plugin type.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That of course works perfectly - I am curious as to why VS Code doesn't auto-import that as I would have expected.